# Realization theory, collection of different forms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, control-theory, linear-control

It is well known that for a given transfer function matrix $G(s)$ there exist in general infinitly many matrices $(A,B,C,D)$ such that

$$
G(s) = C(sI - A)^{-1}B + D
$$

where $s$ is the complex Laplace variable and $I$ the identity matrix.

Three well known "special" realizations are the controllable canonical form, the observable canonical form and the Jordan canonical form.

**Question:** Are there other "special" (or: not so well known) realizations than the three mentioned, which are useful/used for different purposes?

Also a list/reference of such realizations would be very interesting.

Comment: Do you only want to focus on minimal realisations (observable and controllable)?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Good point, but I guess all kinds of "special" realizations would be interesting (minimal or not). I want to collect them in a list.

Comment: Then the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition) would be a good one. Also, do you only want to consider SISO systems or also MIMO systems? Namely the controllable and observable realization are I believe not well defined in the MIMO case.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that form. If there are then other forms for MIMO systems, those as well.